# Why index addition changed nothing in the explain statement here?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, innodb, explain

Here is the script to create table:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS sailors;
USE sailors;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reserves;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sailors;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS boats;

CREATE TABLE sailors
(
sid    INTEGER NOT NULL ,
sname  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
rating INTEGER NULL ,
age    DECIMAL(5,2) NULL, 
CONSTRAINT sailors_pk PRIMARY KEY (sid)
);

CREATE TABLE boats
(
bid    INTEGER NOT NULL ,
bname  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
color  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT boats_pk PRIMARY KEY (bid)
);

CREATE TABLE reserves
(
sid    INTEGER NOT NULL ,
bid    INTEGER NOT NULL ,
day    DATE NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT reserves_pk PRIMARY KEY (sid,bid,day)
, foreign key (sid) references sailors (sid)
, foreign key (bid) references boats  (bid)
);

INSERT INTO sailors VALUES(22, 'Dustin', 7, 45.0);
INSERT INTO sailors VALUES(29, 'Brutus', 1, 33.0);
INSERT INTO sailors VALUES(31, 'Lubber', 8, 55.5);
INSERT INTO sailors VALUES(32, 'Audy',   8, 25.5);
INSERT INTO sailors VALUES(58, 'Rusty', 10, 35.5);
INSERT INTO sailors VALUES(64, 'Horatio',7, 35.0);
INSERT INTO sailors VALUES(71, 'Zorba', 10, 16.0);
INSERT INTO sailors VALUES(74, 'Horatio',9, 35.0);
INSERT INTO sailors VALUES(85, 'Art',    3, 25.5);
INSERT INTO sailors VALUES(95, 'Bob',    3, 63.5);

INSERT INTO boats VALUES(101, 'Interlake', 'blue');
INSERT INTO boats VALUES(102, 'Interlake', 'red');
INSERT INTO boats VALUES(103, 'Clipper',   'green');
INSERT INTO boats VALUES(104, 'Marine',    'red');
INSERT INTO boats VALUES(105, 'Clipper',   'white');

INSERT INTO reserves VALUES(22, 101, DATE '2012-10-10');
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES(22, 102, DATE '2012-10-10');
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES(22, 103, DATE '2012-08-10');
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES(22, 104, DATE '2012-07-10');
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES(31, 102, DATE '2012-10-11');
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES(31, 103, DATE '2012-06-11');
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES(31, 104, DATE '2012-12-11');
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES(64, 101, DATE '2012-05-09');
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES(64, 102, DATE '2012-08-09');
INSERT INTO reserves VALUES(74, 103, DATE '2012-08-09');
```

Here is the script with the `EXPLAIN` statement and the result of it.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM sailors ORDER BY rating;

# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, sailors, , ALL, , , , , 10, 100.00, Using filesort
```

Now I am adding indexes and expect the `EXPLAIN` statement result to change afterwards:

```
CREATE INDEX rating ON sailors(rating);
CREATE INDEX age ON sailors(age);
```

Now I run the `EXPLAIN` statement and see that I changed nothing:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM sailors ORDER BY rating;

# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, sailors, , ALL, , , , , 10, 100.00, Using filesort
```

Why did nothing changed in the `EXPLAIN` statement? What I expected is some performance improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a secondary index (such as `INDEX(rating)`) involves bouncing between the index BTree and the data BTree.  This was determined to be slower than simply reading all the data, then sorting it.  The cutoff varies, but is somewhere around 20% of the table -- that is, if you had a `WHERE` clause that filtered down to less than 20% of the data (and *both* the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY` could be handled together), then the Optimizer would *probably* use the index.

The term "filesort" is a misnomer.  It does not necessarily involve a "file" -- it is often done in RAM.